# Reacjs map data from api to table get while blank screen

Tags: reactjs

I have a data called person in JSON format getting from API in the file User.js:

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState([]);
const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/persons";
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    setPerson(response.data);
  });
}, [url]);
```

In another file called UpdatePersonForm.js I'm trying to show that data in popup windows after clicking a button.

```
export const UpdatePersonForm= ({ person, personEditOnSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {person.map((item) => (
        <tr>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
   </div>
}
```

then it shows a white blank screen again. If I called an API directly from UpdatePersonForm.js then it works fine. For example:

```
export const UpdatePersonForm= ({ personEditOnSubmit }) => {

 const [person, setPerson] = useState([]);
  const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/persons";
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      setPerson(response.data);
    });
  }, [url]);
  return (
    <div>
      {person.map((item) => (
        <tr>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
   </div>
}
```

However, if I get data from the parent file like the above then I got wrong. Anyone know what’s wrong?

Comment: How is the prop `person` passed to the component ?

Comment: Should I add something to make it works?

Comment: How and where are you calling `UpdatePersonForm` component?

Comment: yes something as `<UpdatePersonForm person={person} />` in your `User` component return statement ...

Comment: Maybe person receives undefined as a value. Make sure person get actual value.

Comment: Use optional chaining <td>{item?.name}</td>.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @KcH yes I had it in the User.JS

Comment: @KonradLinkowski it crashes. It always show the white blank page if I get data from parent file

Comment: @ArifurRahaman the person variable is not undefined. I tried console.log(person) in the UpdatePersonForm.js and see there’s a correctt data but when i map into the table it causes white blank screen

Comment: Please show entire error message from the console